# Can I change the URL of a link shared on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I recently migrated a bunch of different corporate sites into one CMS instance, which routes URLs differently than the CMSes that they used to be in.

Now there's a lot of dead links for old posts on the company's Facebook account that are just giving 404 errors on the new site.

Maybe this is simple and I'm just missing it it, but is there any way to edit old posts to update the link addresses?

Comment: I believe you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can only edit the body of a Facebook post. You cannot edit the link attached. There is no way to do this via Facebook.